# How to pass arguments in php exec()?

Tags: php, exec

I am trying to run a .exe application with input file and argument.

With cmd I can successfully start the executable like this...

```
C:\Program Files\MyApp.exe "path\to\input file" argument
```

However, nothing happens when I simply copy paste the string above into the exec() function like this..

```
exec("C:\Program Files\MyApp.exe "path\to\input file" argument")
```

Do I need to escape parts of the string? How should I proceed?

Comment: can you show your php code?

Comment: Please show us your whole statement including the `exec()` call.

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the arguments like a normal calling from shell

ex:

```
exec("C:\Program Files\MyApp.exe \"path to\input file\" argument")
```

Comment: Try `exec("C:\\Program Files\\MyApp.exe \"path to\\input file\" argument")`

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this format

`php -q "./yii.php" migrate/up --interactive=0 --migrationPath=@vendor/pheme/yii2-settings/migrations`